# iOS app using web view crash randomly with no good error message

Tags: xcode, xcode4, jquery-mobile, webkit

I'm working on a iPad app that is mainly a web view. It is served a web app that uses jQuery mobile, iScroll and some minor plugins. The only two plugins that is consistent troughout the app are jQuery mobile and iScroll, so i won't list all the small ones since the same crash can be triggered across the app under all kinds of different circumstances.

The real problem I have is that the only message xCode gives me is a trace of what WebCore is doing exactly before the crash. And i can't make heads or tails of it. I've been looking around all day for a solution to my problems but haven't found anything.

The output looks like this:

```
1   WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext::destroyedActiveDOMObject(WebCore::ActiveDOMObject*)
2   WebCore::ActiveDOMObject::~ActiveDOMObject()
3   WebCore::SuspendableTimer::~SuspendableTimer()
4   WebCore::DOMTimer::~DOMTimer()
5   WebCore::DOMTimer::removeById(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, int)
6   WebCore::DOMWindow::clearTimeout(int)
7   WebCore::jsDOMWindowPrototypeFunctionClearTimeout(JSC::ExecState*)
8   JSC::Interpreter::privateExecute(JSC::Interpreter::ExecutionFlag, JSC::RegisterFile*, JSC::ExecState*)
9   JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&)
10  JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&)
11  WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*)
12  WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul>&)
13  WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*)
14  WebCore::Node::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*)
15  WebCore::EventContext::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*) const
16  WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>)
17  WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const
18  WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WebCore::EventDispatchMediator const&)
19  WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>)
20  WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, int&)
21  WebCore::EventHandler::dispatchTouchEvent(WebCore::PlatformTouchEvent const&, WTF::AtomicString const&, WTF::HashMap<WebCore::EventTarget*, WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::Touch>, 0ul>*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::EventTarget*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::EventTarget*>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::Touch>, 0ul>*> > const&, float, float)
22  WebCore::EventHandler::handleTouchEvent(WebCore::PlatformTouchEvent const&)
23  WebCore::EventHandler::touchEvent(WebEvent*)
24  -[WebHTMLView touch:]
25  -[WAKView _handleEvent:]
26  _ZL13eventCallbackP6WKViewP8WebEventPv
27  _WKViewHandleEvent
28  WKWindowSendEvent
29  -[UIWebBrowserView _dispatchWebEvent:]
30  -[UIWebBrowserView _webTouchEventsRecognized:]
31  -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
```

The only real error I'm getting is `Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"`

Thanks in advance, I'm glad for any help. Just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that i finally solved the problem. Thought i would share it here.

I still don't know exactly what made the application crash, but the fix i figured out seems to have solved the issue.

So since all i got in the output in xcode was something from webkits core (at least i figured as much with my limited knowledge about this), this led me to start looking at the website that is feeding the webview.

I've read a lot about problems with html5 video in mobile devices so i started to look there. I turned of all JavaScript and fed the site a single html 5 video element. All went fine, though when adding back jQuery-mobile the crashes returned as soon as i tried scrolling at the same time as the video was playing.

I know from before that there are some problems with using poster images on iOS devices. So i removed this, well that did the trick.

*So to sum this up:*

This is what i had:

```
<video class="videoSignPlayer" poster="poster.jpg" width="768" height="512" style="display:none;">
    <source src="movie.mp4" width="768" type='video/mp4;
     codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

This is the working markup:

```
<video class="videoSignPlayer" width="768" height="512" style="display:none;">
    <source src="movie.mp4" width="768" type='video/mp4;
     codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

Simple Fix.

**It seems like there is a problem with having the poster attribute on a video element when using jQuery-mobile.**

(And yes, i also tried preloading the poster image in a `<img>` tag. The only solution to the crashes was to completly remove the poster attribute on the `<video>` tag.)